# At most how many common arithmetic progressions passing through 2 numbers in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

Given a positive prime number $p$. 
An $k$-term arithmetic progression ($k$-AP) in $\mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (modulo $p$ classes) is defined as a set $\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$ of $k$ numbers in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ so that
$$a_i=a_1+(i-1)d$$
for some $d\neq 0$ and all $i=1,\dots,k$.

**Question:** Assume $3\le k\ll p$. For two distinct numbers $a,b$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, let
$$\mathcal{S}(a,b):=\{S\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_p: |S|=k-1, S\cup\{a\}\text { and }S\cup\{b\}\text{ are both $k$-APs}\}.$$
Can you give an upper bound $f(k)$ on $\max_{a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_P:a\neq b}|\mathcal{S}(a,b)|$, where $f(k)$ is a function only depending on $k$ (but not $p$)?

**Example:** Given $a=1,b=4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p$ large enough and $k=3$, then $S=\{3,5\}$ is one of what we should count, as $\{1,3,5\}$ and $\{3,4,5\}$ are both $3$-term arithmetic progressions in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. $\{2,3\}$ is another one we should count. So if some upper bound $f(k)$ exists, it should be at least 2.

**Idea:** Someone claims $k^6$ is an upper bound. And their reason is that assume $x_1,x_2\in S$ and the positions of $x_1,x_2$ in the arithmetic progressions containing $a$ are $i_1,i_2$, respectively, and are $j_1,j_2$ for the other arithmetic progression containing $b$. Similarly assume $a,b$ are in the $i,j$ places of these arithmetic progressions, respectively. When $i_1,i_2,j_1,j_2,i,j$ are determined (in at most $k^6$ ways), the differences $d_1,d_2$ of two arithmetic progressions can be determined. Then it will be done.

But I am not sure why it is true.
As we can establish linear equations for unknowns $x_1,x_2,d_1,d_2$ as
$$x_1-a=(i_1-i)d_1$$
$$x_1-b=(j_1-j)d_2$$
$$x_2-a=(i_2-i)d_1$$
$$x_2-b=(j_2-j)d_2.$$
But the determinant of the coefficient matrix will be $(i_2-i)(j-j_1)+(i-i_1)(j-j_2)$. I don't know why it is nonzero even we can assume $i,i_1,i_2$ are distinct and $j,j_1,j_2$ are distinct.

Comment: Could you give a non-trivial example for, e.g. $k = 4$? I fail to see why there can be so many different choices of $S$.

Comment: An upper of form $f(k)$ (a function only depends on $k$) works for me.

Comment: There are trivial upper bounds like $(k!)^2$. By specifying the order of the $k - 1$ elements together with $a$ and $b$, the set $S$ is totally determined. That is, if I understand the question correctly...

Comment: @WhatsUp how many linear equations do you need?

Comment: @WhatsUp here $a,b$ are given, we need to bound the number of $S$.

Comment: @WhatsUp I added an example to explain it

Comment: I suddenly realized that I probably totally misunderstood the question. To clarify: by $\mathbb Z_p$ do you mean $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$? I understood it as the $p$-adic numbers... Although for $k<<p$ it probably doesn't make a big difference, it might help clarify the question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Can you make the $k\ge 4$ argument a rigorous proof?

Comment: @WhatsUp You new understanding is correct. It is $\mathbb{Z}$ module $p$. And I try to avoid some not interesting case to make $p$ larger than $k$.

Comment: It is enough to give an upper bound that only depends on $k$ on the number of such sets. Is it possible to get one?

Answer (score 1):

#### Preliminaries

For notational convenience, let $AP_k(a_0, d) = \{a_0 + jd \,|\, 0 \le j < k\}$ be the arithmetic progression of $k$ elements with first term $a_0$ and step $d$. Note that $AP_k(a_0, d) = AP_k(a_0 + (k-1)d, -d)$ by reindexing. In the rest of this post, the use of this notation implies that $d \neq 0$.

---

We work entirely over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. This is a field, so it's possible to divide by any non-zero value.

---

The number of solutions is a function of $p$ and $k$ and is independent of $a$ and $b$. Proof: if $a \neq b$ and $c \neq d$ the map $z \to (d-c)(b-a)^{-1}(z-a) + c$ is a linear (i.e. preserves arithmetic progressions) bijection which maps solutions for $(a, b)$ to solutions for $(c, d)$.

---

By a very similar argument, given two APs of the same length we can map one to the other with a linear bijection. Therefore we can map the AP containing $a$ to $AP_k(0, 1)$. If $k = 1$ then $|S| = 0$ and there is exactly one solution. Otherwise the linear bijection which maps the AP to $AP_k(0, 1)$ is unique and we can reduce the question which we need to address to:

> Given $k$, for how many $a \in AP_k(0, 1)$ and $b \not\in AP_k(0, 1)$ can we find $x$, $d$ such that $AP_k(x, d) = AP_k(0, 1) \setminus \{a\} \cup \{b\}$?

Proof: let $$\mathbb{S} = \left\{ (\alpha, x_\alpha, d_\alpha, \beta, x_\beta, d_\beta) \;\Bigg|\; \begin{array}{c} \alpha \in AP_k(x_\alpha, d_\alpha), \\ \beta \in AP_k(x_\beta, d_\beta), \\ AP_k(x_\alpha, d_\alpha) \setminus \{\alpha\} = AP_k(x_\beta, d_\beta) \setminus \{\beta\} \end{array} \right\}$$
and filter it two ways:
$$T_{a,b} = \{ (a, x_a, d_a, b, x_b, d_b) \in \mathbb{S} \} \\
U = \{ (\alpha, 0, 1, \beta, x_\beta, d_\beta) \in \mathbb{S} \}$$

Then $$f(a, x_a, d_a, b, x_b, d_b) = (d_a^{-1}(a - x_a), 0, 1, d_a^{-1}(b - x_a), d_a^{-1}(x_b - x_a), d_a^{-1} d_b)$$ is an injection from $T_{a,b}$ to $U$, and $$g(\alpha, 0, 1, \beta, x_\beta, d_\beta) = \begin{array}{l} (a, (b - a)(\beta - \alpha)^{-1}(- \alpha) + a, (b - a)(\beta - \alpha)^{-1}, \\ b, (b - a)(\beta - \alpha)^{-1}(x_\beta - \alpha) + a, (b - a)(\beta - \alpha)^{-1} d_\beta) \end{array}$$ is an injection from $U$ to $T_{a,b}$.

---

To avoid double-counting due to the symmetry mentioned in the first paragraph, we place the additional constraint that $a \in AP_{\lceil k/2 \rceil}(0, 1)$.

---

#### Solutions for extreme values of $k$

We've already seen that when $k = 1$ there is exactly one solution to the original problem.

When $k > 1$ there is one easy solution: $a = 0$, $b = k$, $x = 0$, $d = 1$.

When $k = p-1$ the choice of $a$ and $b$ fixes $S$ and this is the only solution.

When $k = 2$, since any two elements form an AP, there are $p-2$ solutions. (Given $a$ and $b$, pick any of the other elements in the field to be the single element in $S$).

Similarly, when $k = p - 2$, there are $p - 2$ solutions. (Given $a$ and $b$, pick any of the other elements and call it $c$. Then we can make $c$ the only element not to be in either AP by choosing $x$, $d$ such that $x + (p-2)d = c$, $x + (p-1)d = a$, and we can achieve this by setting $d = a - c$, $x = a + d$).

Finally, when $k < 1$ or $k \ge p$ there is no candidate $S$ which even has the right number of elements.

---

#### Solutions for $2 < k < p - 2$

There's the same easy solution: $a = 0$, $b = k$, $x = 0$, $d = 1$.

This is the only solution with $d = 1$. Proof: if $d = 1$ and $a = 0$ then since $0 \not\in AP_k(0, 1) \setminus \{a\} \cup \{b\}$ we must have $1$ as an endpoint, so $AP_k(0, 1) \setminus \{a\} \cup \{b\} = AP_k(1, 1)$ forcing $b = k$. But if $a \neq 0$ then the endpoints must be $a+1$ and $a-1$, so $AP_k(0, 1) \setminus \{a\} \cup \{b\} = A_{p-1}(a+1, 1)$, forcing $b = p-1 = k$.

---

That leaves possible solutions where $d > 1$.

Remember that $AP_k(x, d) \setminus \{b\} = AP_k(0, 1) \setminus \{a\}$. There are at most two elements $e$ in $AP_k(x, d) \setminus \{b\}$ for which we're not certain that $(e + d) \in AP_k(x, d) \setminus \{b\}$, namely $e_1 = x + (k-1)d$ and $e_2 = b - d$. (These may be the same element, and if they aren't then the first will be in the set iff $k = p$). Therefore
$$\left| \big(AP_k(0, 1) \setminus \{a\}\big) \cap \big(AP_k(d, 1) \setminus \{a + d\}\big) \right| \ge k - 3$$
which we can rearrange to
$$\left| \big(AP_k(0, 1) \cap AP_k(d, 1) \big) \setminus \{a, a + d\} \right| \ge k - 3$$

If $k + d < p$ then $AP_k(d, 1)$ can't wrap around to include $0$, so we lose $d$ elements from the start of $AP_k(0, 1)$, yielding $|AP_k(0, 1) \cap AP_k(d, 1)| = \max(k-d, 0)$. So we have $$\max(k-d, 0) \ge \left| \big(AP_k(0, 1) \cap AP_k(d, 1) \big) \setminus \{a, a + d\} \right| \ge k - 3$$ which has solutions only when $\max(k-d, 0) \ge k - 3$; i.e. if $k > d$ then $d \le 3$; otherwise $k \le 3$ (and we've already exhausted $k < 3$).

When $k = 3$, examination of all possible choices of $a$ and assignments of index in the other AP to the surviving elements of $AP_k(0, 1)$ yields two solutions: $a = 0$, $b = (p+3)/2$, $x = 2$, $d = (p-1)/2$ and $a = 1$, $b = 4$, $x = 0$, $d = 2$.

When $d = 2$ and $k > 3$, $AP_k(0, 1) \cap AP_k(d, 1) = AP_{k-2}(2,1)$ has $k - 2$ elements, so it contains at most one of $\{a, a+d\}$.

- Subcase: $a = 0$. Since $2 \in AP_k(0, 1) \setminus \{a\}$ and $2 - d = a \neq b$ is not in $AP_k(0, 1) \setminus \{a\} \cup \{b\}$, it must be the end-point corresponding to $i=0$, and the second AP is $AP_k(2, 2)$. Then since $1 \in AP_k(0, 1) \setminus \{a\}$ doesn't correspond to $i=0$ we must have $1 - d \equiv p-1 \in AP_k(2, 2)$, so $b = p-1$, and similarly we must have $b - d = p - 3 \in AP_k(2, 2)$. Therefore $p - 3 < k$, and we've handled this above in the section on extreme cases.
- Subcase: $a = 1$. Since $3 \in AP_k(0, 1) \setminus \{a\}$ and $3 - d = a \neq b$ is not in $AP_k(0, 1) \setminus \{a\} \cup \{b\}$, it must be the end-point corresponding to $i=0$, and the second AP is $AP_k(3, 2)$. Then since $0 \in AP_k(0, 1) \setminus \{a\}$ doesn't correspond to $i=0$ we must have $p - 2 \in AP_k(3, 2)$, so $b = p-2$, and similarly we must have $b - d = p - 4 \in AP_k(3, 2)$. Therefore $p - 4 < k$, and the only case we haven't handled above in the section on extreme cases is $k = p - 3$, where we have a solution.
- Subcase: $2 \le a < k$. Then either $a + 2 \in \{0, 1\}$ (so $a \in \{p-2, p-1\}$, and since $a < k$ that means $k \ge p-1$ and we've handled this above) or $a + 2 \ge k$ (and since $a < k$ that means that $a \in \{k-2, k-1\}$ and we're violating the symmetry-breaking constraint that $a \in AP_{\lceil k/2 \rceil}(0, 1)$).

When $d = 3 < k$, $|AP_k(0, 1) \cap AP_k(d, 1)| = k - 3$, so we require $a \not\in AP_k(0, 1) \cap AP_k(d, 1)$, so $a < d$. But we also require $(a + d) \not\in AP_k(0, 1) \cap AP_k(d, 1)$, so $a + d \ge k$, which requires $k \le 5$. This gives us two subcases:

- $d = 3$, $k = 4$. Since $a < d$ we can further subcase:

  - $a = 0$: then $\{1,2,3,b\}$ is an AP with step 3. But $\{b-3, b+3\}$ can only cover two elements of the other three, and they all need at least one neighbour.
  - $a = 1$: then $\{0,2,3,b\}$ is an AP with step 3. Considering all possible sequences and the implications for $p$ (e.g. if the AP in order is $[2,b,0,3]$ then two steps take $2$ to $0$, so $-2 \equiv 6 \pmod p$ and the only prime which satisfies that is $p = 2$) we find no solutions for which $k + d < p$.
  - $a = 2$: then $\{0,1,3,b\}$ is an AP with step 3. Similarly, we find no solutions for which $k + d < p$.
- $d = 3$, $k = 5$. We against split by $a$ and consider permutations.

  - $a = 0$: $\{1,2,3,4,b\}$ is an AP with step 3. Nothing with primes greater than $8$.
  - $a = 1$: Similarly.
  - $a = 2$: Similarly.

---

If $k + d \ge p$ then $AP_k(d, 1)$ loops round, ending at $d + (k-1) - p$. (Note that $k + d \ge 2p$ is impossible because they're both less than $p$). Therefore the intersection $AP_k(0, 1) \cap AP_k(d, 1)$ has $k - d + (d + k - p) = 2k - p$ elements. $2k - p \ge k - 3$ implies $k \ge p - 3$, and we've already considered $k \ge p - 2$, so it only remains to consider $k = p - 3$.

An observation which we'll use a lot is that every AP of $p$ elements covers the entire field. (Proof: if we have a cycle in an AP, $d$ times the length of that cycle must be divisible by $p$. But $p$ is coprime with every number smaller than it, including $d$). So the three elements *not* in $AP_{p-3}(x, d)$ are $\{x - d, x - 2d, x - 3d\}$.

We note that when $k = p - 3$, $|AP_k(0, 1) \cap AP_k(d, 1)| = p-6 = k-3$ so we require $a \not\in AP_k(0, 1) \cap AP_k(d, 1)$ and $(a + d) \not\in AP_k(0, 1) \cap AP_k(d, 1)$. The first of those constraints, combined with $a \in AP_k(0, 1)$, gives us $a \in \{d-1, d-2, d-3\}$; and the second gives us $(a + d) \in \{d-1, d-2, d-3, p-1, p-2, p-3\}$ (but since $a \not\in \{p-1, p-2, p-3\}$ that means $(a + d) \in \{p-1, p-2, p-3\}$). That's not many cases to consider, and once we eliminate those where $d \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$ we're left with three candidates for $a$ and $d$. We also have $b \in \{p-1, p-2, p-3\}$; more precisely, by considering the elements not in $S$, we have $\{a, p-1, p-2, p-3\} = \{b, x - d, x - 2d, x - 3d\}$.

- $a = d-1$, $a + d = p-2$, so $d = (p-1)/2$. But then $2a = k$ so we violate the symmetry-breaking constraint.
- $a = d-2$, $a + d = p-3$, so $d = (p-1)/2$. $\{a, p-1, p-2, p-3\} = \{b, x - d, x + 1, x + 1 - d \}$

  - If $a = x - d$, $x = p - 3$ and $\{p-1, p-2, p-3\} = \{b, p-2, (p-3)/2 \}$ so $p \in \{-1, 3\}$ and $p - 3 \le 0$ is already handled in the extremes.
  - If $a = x + 1$, $x = d - 3$ and $\{p-1, p-2, p-3\} = \{b, p-3, p-2 \}$ so $b = p - 1$ and we have a solution.
  - If $a = x + 1 - d$, $x = p-4$ and $\{p-1, p-2, p-3\} = \{b, (p-7)/2, p-3 \}$ so $p \in \{-5, -3\}$.
- $a = d-3$, $a + d = p-2$, so $d = (p+1)/2$. These are symmetric pairs of the case $a = d-2$, $d = (p-1)/2$.

---

#### Summary

- $k = 1$ has the trivial solution $S = \emptyset$
- $k = 2$ or $k = p - 2$ has $p - 2$ solutions.
- $k = 3$ has three solutions, isomorphic to $(0, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1)$, $(0, 0, 1, (p+3)/2, 2, (p-1)/2)$, $(1, 0, 1, 4, 0, 2)$
- $k = p - 3$ has three solutions, isomorphic to $(0, 0, 1, p-3, 1, 1)$, $(1, 0, 1, p-2, 3, 2)$, $((p-5)/2, 0, 1, p-1, (p-7)/2, (p-1)/2)$
- All other $4 \le k < p$ have one solution, isomorphic to $(0, 0, 1, k, 1, 1)$

Unwrapping the isomorphisms,

- $k = 1$ has the trivial solution $S = \emptyset$
- $k = 2$ or $k = p - 2$ has $p - 2$ solutions.
- $k = 3$ has three solutions,
      $$
    \left(a, a, 3^{-1}(b - a), b, 3^{-1}(b - a) + a, 3^{-1}(b - a) \right) \\
    \left(a, a, (b - a)\left(\frac{p+3}2 \right)^{-1}, b, 2(b - a)\left(\frac{p+3}2\right)^{-1} + a, (b - a)\left(\frac{p+3}2\right)^{-1} \frac{p-1}2 \right) \\
    \left(a, 3^{-1}(b - a) + a, -3^{-1}(b - a), b, 3^{-1}(b - a) + a, -3^{-1} 2(b - a) \right) $$
- $k = p - 3$ has three solutions,
      $$
    \left(a, a, -3^{-1}(b - a), b, -3^{-1}(b - a) + a, -3^{-1}(b - a) \right) \\
    \left(a, 3^{-1}(b - a) + a, -3^{-1}(b - a), b, -3^{-1}2(b - a) + a, -3^{-1}2(b - a) \right) \\
    \left(a, (b - a)\left(\frac{p+3}{2}\right)^{-1}\left(- \frac{p-5}2\right) + a, (b - a)\left(\frac{p+3}{2}\right)^{-1}, b, -(b - a)\left(\frac{p+3}{2}\right)^{-1} + a, (b - a)\left(\frac{p+3}{2}\right)^{-1} \frac{p-1}2 \right) $$
- All other $4 \le k < p$ have one solution, $$(a, a, (b - a)k^{-1}, b, (b - a)k^{-1} + a, (b - a)k^{-1})$$

Comment: I am not sure why the question can be reduced to what you address. In your notations, I think my question is given distinct $a$ and $b$, there are (at most) how many $A_k(s_1,d_1)$ and $A_k(s_2,d_2)$ for any $s_1,s_2,d_1,d_2$ so that $|A_k(s_1,d_1)\cap A_k(s_2,d_2)|=k-1$, $a\in A_k(s_1,d_1)\setminus A_k(s_2,d_2)$ and $b\in A_k(s_2,d_2)\setminus A_k(s_1,d_1)$?

Comment: As those $k$-term arithmetic progression we consider may have different differences ($d$ in the $A_k(c,d)$), I am not sure we can use a single linear transformation to map all of them to a difference 1 $k$-AP simultaneously.

Comment: @Connor, indeed. I don't intend to suggest that it should be the same transformation for all of the solutions. The claim is that for every solution there is a transformation. Perhaps I need to explicitly address the question of whether distinct solutions could map to the same $AP_k(0,1)$ and $AP_k(x,d)$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think what you answered is that given a $k$-term arithmetic progression $A$, at most 1 pair $(a,b)$ so that $a\in A$ and $b\not\in A$ and $(A \setminus \{a\} ) \cup \{b\}$ is a $k$-AP (for general $k$). But I think this is not what I want, because the $k$-AP containing $a$ can vary, your answer will just lead to some bound around $p$, I think?

Comment: I've added more detail there, as well as fixing an error and filling in the remaining cases.

Answer (score 0):

By writing down the restriction as
$$x_1-x_2=(i_1-i_2)d_1$$
$$x_1-a=(i_1-i)d_1$$
$$x_1-x_2=(j_1-j_2)d_2$$
$$x_1-b=(j_1-j)d_2$$
and treat $x_1,x_2,d_1,d_2$ as unknowns, the determinant of the coefficient matrix is
$$(j_1-j_2)(i_1-i)-(j_1-j)(i_1-i_2),$$
which is non-zero, otherwise 
$$\frac{x_1-a}{x_1-x_2}=\frac{x_1-b}{x_1-x_2},$$
which implies $a=b$, contradiction, by $i_1,i_2,i$ are distinct, $j_1,j_2,j$ are distinct and $d_1,d_2$ are nonzero, and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field.
So there are at most $f(k)\le k^6$. (More explicitly, $f(k)\le (k(k-1)(k-2))^2$ by above argument.)